# Update an Entity with Unique Key - Insert instead of update

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this method in my service:

```
public function updateCountry($p_entity) {   


    var_dump($p_entity->getId());    //return 3 (as expected)
    var_dump(get_class($p_entity) ); //return Country (as expected)

    $this->em->persist($p_entity);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

I call it by

```
$country = $em->getRepository('blabla')->find(3);
$my_service->updateCountry($country);
```

But the request generated is

> Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing
>   'INSERT INTO country (code, label , created_at, updated_at)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["EN", "England", "201
>   3-08-23 00:00:00", null]:

I have a unique doctrine constraint

this is my country.orm.yml

```
To\Bundle\Entity\Country:
    type: entity
    table: country
    repositoryClass: To\Bundle\Entity\CountryRepository

    fields:
         id:
             type: integer
             id: true
             generator:
                 strategy: AUTO
         code:
             type: string
             length: 255
             unique: true
             nullable: false
```

Why have I an **insert** request generated instead of the **update** one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you persist new entity at all?

If you can, try merging your object instead:

```
public function updateCountry($p_entity) {
    var_dump($p_entity->getId());    //return 3 (as expected)
    var_dump(get_class($p_entity) ); //return Country (as expected)

    $this->em->merge($p_entity); // MERGE not PERSIST
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

From official docs:

> If X is a new entity instance, a new managed copy X’ will be created
>   and the state of X is copied onto this managed instance.

So, basically, `EntityManager::merge` can be used to both persist newly created object and merge exsistent one...

Comment: This solve the problem! But can you link me the doc reference? i only find  information about merge like:  
the most common scenario for the merge operation is to reattach entities to an EntityManager that come from some cache (and are therefore detached) and you want to modify and persist such an entity.

Comment: I found it : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html . Even with the doc it's still a bit obscure for me, if you can try to develop the why I would offeryou my elder sister

Comment: Merge certainly works but what you should be doing is to retrieve the existing country entity (using a find), then update the entity and flush it.  That is why you don't see merge used much.  It's seldom needed during normal retrieve/update/flush workflow.

Comment: I agree with @Cerad. While using `merge` is "no brainier" it certainly is not commonly used mainly because people want to have more control over what is persisted. Have you notices that auto-generated entities have no setter for id field? That is because you should first `find()` an entity and then apply changes to it.

Comment: My entity is already finded, and linked to the ORM. I agree you couldn't know it

Comment: Based on your updated question, I'm guessing that you are using two different entity managers?

Comment: Yes, but they have the same php internal object id

Comment: EntityManager:merge is deprecated :/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't persist existing in DB entity, only new one.
So if you get entity from DB and want to update it
you should

1. $entity->setName()
2. $em->flush

Comment: This is not right. You will think it worked because you are looking at an updated but not-persisted entity. If you read it again from scratch you will see it has not changed.

Comment: Using Doctrine to edit an existing product consists of three steps:

    fetching the object from Doctrine;
    modifying the object;
    calling flush() on the entity manager.

You can call $entityManager->persist($product), but it isn’t necessary: Doctrine is already “watching” your object for changes.Check it from https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#updating-an-object