# The controller must return a response (1 given). 500 Internal Server Error - LogicException

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I started out with the following controller code

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\events;
//use AppBundle\Entity\eventtype;
use AppBundle\Entity\users;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $events = new events();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($events)
                ->add('eT1', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Poker' => 1,
                        'Chess' => 2,
                        'Cricket' => 3,
                        'Marbles' => 4,
                        'Football' => 5,
                    ),
                    'choices_as_values' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'label' => 'Choose After Breakfast Event',
                ))
                ->add('eT2', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Poker' => 1,
                        'Chess' => 2,
                        'Cricket' => 3,
                        'Marbles' => 4,
                        'Football' => 5,
                    ),
                    'choices_as_values' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'label' => 'Choose After Snacks Event',
                ))
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
                ->getForm();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->submit($request);

            $formData = $form->getData();

            //check to see if the after breakfast event (eT1) is full (ie.has reached the maxlimit)
            //for now the maxLimit is set to 4
            $ET1 = $formData->getET1();

            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:events');
            $query1 = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->select('count(p)')
                    ->where('p.eT1 = :eT1')
                    ->setParameter('eT1', $ET1)
                    ->getQuery();
            $a = $query1->getSingleScalarResult();

            if ($a >= $maxLimit=4) {
                echo 'choose another event, this one is full';
            }
            else{
               return $ET1; 
            }

            //check to see if the after snacks event (eT2) is full (ie.has reached the maxlimit)
            //for now the maxLimit is set to 4
            $ET2 = $formData->getET2();

            $query2 = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->select('count(p)')
                    ->where('p.eT2 = :eT2')
                    ->setParameter('eT2', $ET2)
                    ->getQuery();
            $b = $query2->getSingleScalarResult();

            if ($b >= $maxLimit=4) {
                echo 'choose another event, this one is full';
            }
            else{
               return $ET2; 
            }

            //get the user_id of the logged in user
            $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $events->setUser($user);
            $x = $events->getUser()->getID();

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                //check if the user has already registered or not
                $y = $repository->findOneBy(array('user' => $x));

                // If the user is registering for the first time (execute the insert query)
                if (!$y) {                    
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->persist($events);
                    $em->flush();
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
                } 

                //If the user has registered already and want change his registered events (execute the update query)
                else {                    
                    $formData = $form->getData();
                    $ET1 = $formData->getET1();
                    $ET2 = $formData->getET2();
                    $events->setET1($ET1);
                    $events->setET2($ET2);

                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->persist($events);
                    $em->flush();
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

}
```

But then i modified the code to display different pages for a user who has already registered and who is registering for the for the first time.
The following code gives the error - The controller must return a response (1 given). 500 Internal Server Error - LogicException
My guess is that the error lies in statements `return $ET1;` and `return $ET2;`
 
Here are the questions I cannot find answers to:
1. Why the error - The controller must return a response (1 given). 500 Internal Server Error - LogicException
2. I have to repeat the same code twice, for new user and already registered user. Is there a work around?
3. How do i set the different $maxLimit parameter values for different events(eg. for poker=12, chess=4, cricket=10 etc.) from inside the config.yml file?

Here is the modified controller code

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\events;
//use AppBundle\Entity\eventtype;
use AppBundle\Entity\users;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $events = new events();
        // check if the user is registering for the first time or else
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $events->setUser($user);
        $x = $events->getUser()->getID();

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:events');
        $y = $repository->findOneBy(array('user' => $x));

        // If the user is registering for the first time (execute the insert query)
        if (!$y) {
            echo 'Welcome to the Birthday party';
            echo 'You can choose from the below options:';

            $form = $this->createFormBuilder($events)
                    ->add('eT1', ChoiceType::class, array(
                        'choices' => array(
                            'Poker' => 1,
                            'Chess' => 2,
                            'Cricket' => 3,
                            'Marbles' => 4,
                            'Football' => 5,
                        ),
                        'choices_as_values' => true,
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'label' => 'After Breakfast Event',
                    ))
                    ->add('eT2', ChoiceType::class, array(
                        'choices' => array(
                            'Poker' => 1,
                            'Chess' => 2,
                            'Cricket' => 3,
                            'Marbles' => 4,
                            'Football' => 5,
                        ),
                        'choices_as_values' => true,
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'label' => 'After Snacks Event',
                    ))
                    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
                    ->getForm();

            if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
                $form->submit($request);

                $formData = $form->getData();

                //check to see if the after breakfast event (eT1) is full (ie.has reached the maxlimit)
                $ET1 = $formData->getET1();

                $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:events');
                $query1 = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->select('count(p)')
                        ->where('p.eT1 = :eT1')
                        ->setParameter('eT1', $ET1)
                        ->getQuery();
                $a = $query1->getSingleScalarResult();
//            var_dump($a);
//            exit;
                if ($a >= $maxLimit = 4) {
                    echo 'choose another event, this one is full';
                } else {
                    return $ET1;
                }

                //check to see if the after snacks event (eT2) is full (ie.has reached the maxlimit)
                $ET2 = $formData->getET2();

                $query2 = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->select('count(p)')
                        ->where('p.eT2 = :eT2')
                        ->setParameter('eT2', $ET2)
                        ->getQuery();
                $b = $query2->getSingleScalarResult();
//            var_dump($a);
//            exit;
                if ($b >= $maxLimit = 4) {
                    echo 'choose another event, this one is full';
                } else {
                    return $ET2;
                }

                if ($form->isValid()) {

                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    // tells Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
                    $em->persist($events);

                    // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
                    $em->flush();
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
                }
            }
        }
        // If the user has registered already and want change his registered events (execute the update query)
        else {
            echo 'Welcome back';
            echo 'You registered for:';
            echo 'After Breakfast event:.$eventName.';
            echo 'After Snacks event:.$eventName.';
            echo 'You can change your selection by choosing again from below options:';

            $form = $this->createFormBuilder($events)
                    ->add('eT1', ChoiceType::class, array(
                        'choices' => array(
                            'Poker' => 1,
                            'Chess' => 2,
                            'Cricket' => 3,
                            'Marbles' => 4,
                            'Football' => 5,
                        ),
                        'choices_as_values' => true,
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'label' => 'After Breakfast Event',
                    ))
                    ->add('eT2', ChoiceType::class, array(
                        'choices' => array(
                            'Poker' => 1,
                            'Chess' => 2,
                            'Cricket' => 3,
                            'Marbles' => 4,
                            'Football' => 5,
                        ),
                        'choices_as_values' => true,
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'label' => 'After Snacks Event',
                    ))
                    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
                    ->getForm();

            if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
                $form->submit($request);

                $formData = $form->getData();

                //check to see if the after Breakfast event (eT1) is full (ie.has reached the maxlimit)
                $ET1 = $formData->getET1();

                $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:events');
                $query1 = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->select('count(p)')
                        ->where('p.eT1 = :eT1')
                        ->setParameter('eT1', $ET1)
                        ->getQuery();
                $a = $query1->getSingleScalarResult();
//            var_dump($a);
//            exit;
                if ($a >= $maxLimit = 4) {
                    echo 'choose another event, this one is full';
                } else {
                    return $ET1;
                }

                //check to see if the after snacks event (eT2) is full (ie.has reached the maxlimit)
                $ET2 = $formData->getET2();

                $query2 = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->select('count(p)')
                        ->where('p.eT2 = :eT2')
                        ->setParameter('eT2', $ET2)
                        ->getQuery();
                $b = $query2->getSingleScalarResult();
//            var_dump($a);
//            exit;
                if ($b >= $maxLimit = 4) {
                    echo 'choose another event, this one is full';
                } else {
                    return $ET2;

                    if ($form->isValid()) {

                        $formData = $form->getData();
                        $ET1 = $formData->getET1();
                        $ET2 = $formData->getET2();
                        $events->setET1($ET1);
                        $events->setET2($ET2);
                        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                        $em->persist($events);
                        $em->flush();
                        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }

}
```

Below is the users entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\usersRepository")
 */
class users extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="events", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $event;


//    public function __construct()
//    {
//        parent::__construct(); 
//         }

    }
```

Below is the events entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * events
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="events")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\eventsRepository")
 */
class events {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ET1", type="integer")
     */
    protected $eT1;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ET2", type="integer")
     */
    protected $eT2;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="users", inversedBy="event")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
        protected $user;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param users $user
     * @return events
     */
    public function setUser($user) {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return events
     */
    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }


    /**
     * Set eT1
     *
     * @param integer $eT1
     * @return events
     */
    public function setET1($eT1) {
        $this->eT1 = $eT1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eT1
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getET1() {
        return $this->eT1;
    }

    /**
     * Set eT2
     *
     * @param integer $eT2
     * @return events
     */
    public function setET2($eT2) {
        $this->eT2 = $eT2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eT2
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getET2() {
        return $this->eT2;
    }

//    public function __construct()
//    {
//        parent::__construct();
//    }
}
```

Comment: usually you need to return a `Response` object in a controller method.

Comment: You are returning from your controller at `return $ET1;` and `return $ET2;`, those are just values not response objects. Also don't output content (`echo`) in your controller.

Comment: I need the values $ET1 and $ET2.  what should i replace the code `if ($a >= $maxLimit=4) {
                echo 'choose another event, this one is full';
            }
            else{
               return $ET1; 
            }` with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your first question: the Controller must always return an object of type Response, if it cannot return a response object then it must forward the control by doing an internal sub-request to a controller that does return a response object. in symfony, twig templates are used to display the outputs to the user, using

`return $this->render('navigation/homepage.html.twig', array('et1' => $et1, 'et2' => $et2));`

would make the two variables et1 and et2 to be available in the `homepage.html.twig` template.

to answer the second question: you get the current logged in user by doing `$this->getUser()` which is a short cut for security.context token [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/cfd7e8bb0d1bf19d2c6aa1a57e20c5ac98c2c4c4/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L214)

i'm making a guess here, you are trying to check if the userId matches with a userId of an 'events' object, you consider it to be a returning user, and if it does't then its a new user, on that premise

```
$user = $this->getUser()->getUserId();
$event = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:events')->findOneBy(array('user' => $this->getUser()->getUserId() ));
if($event instanceof events){ //events refers to 'events' entity
// code to handle returning user
}
```

answer to the third question: avoid using Global variables, by using config.yml to store maxValue, you are making maxValue available for the entire project. you could change things up in your code to not use golbal variables, but just for the sake of answering a question

store your global variables inside parameters.yml instead of config.yml just to keep things understandable, do something like this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#canonical-parameters)

```
parameters:
    cricketMaxLimit: 10
```

retrieve it with `$cricMaxLimit = $this->container->getParameter('cricketMaxLimit');`

sidenote: stuff like `if ($a >= $maxLimit = 4)` should not even exist in this world, do `if ($a >= 4)`

-dheeraj :)

Answer (score 1):

Elements like `$ET2` and `$ET2` are no responses but are `formData` arrays, Symfony expects you to return a response so make sure to render it into a view, or maybe return it as data via a new `JsonResponse` object?

You could also add the [`@Template` annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html) in order to be able to return data. That annotation tells Symfony that a template should be rendered based on the returned data.

Comment: NOPE! @template is a resource hog, avoid it http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/best_practices/controllers.html#template-configuration

Comment: I'm not saying you should, but you should at least return a valid response instead of the formData array (which that annotation could handle for you). Next to that, the best practice does not relate to the "resource hog" you mention but to the magic it applies that is unclear to beginning developers. All annotations are cached automatically by Symfony so if your action should always return a template this actually improves performance ;)

Answer (score 0):

your controller is unreadable... You may want to put your business code in services, formTypes in dedicated classes and queries into repository classes.

I think you don't go inside the `if(!$y )` condition

Put at the end:

```
return $this->render('default/index.html.twig'));
```

Comment: sorry, I am new to this. Will try to get better at it :)

Comment: I am not able to figure out why `if(!$y)` condition is not being executed

Comment: the code actually goes inside the condition. but it executes insert instead of update querry and gives the following error. An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO events (ET1, ET2, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [2, 5, 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_5387574AA76ED395'

Comment: But it does not go always in all your conditions. for example your if($form->isValid()) has no else condition. No problem i know you are learning but you still have to do better controller ;)

Comment: @utkarsh2k2 I STRONGLY recommend that you read the symfony documentation! I see several fundamentally flawed approaches in how you use the framework.

Comment: @goto why is the doctrine executing insert instead of update? I saw u had a same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118421/update-an-entity-with-unique-key-insert-instead-of-update

Comment: @goto I do not want to use merge. Previously my code was working fine without merge. I dont know what went wrong

Comment: Sorry dude you code is too messy for me I don't have the courage to try it home. The insert/update problem is not relevant here