# Symfony 3 - Save as copy

Tags: php, entity, symfony

I'm trying to save an entity as a copy. The same form will have two submit buttons, one to save and  overwrite and another one to save as a copy.

Save and overwrite work properly, can't say the same for the save as a copy, so far I'd found different problems in my approaches.

This is the action in my controller:

```
public function EditAction($id, Request $request)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $checklist = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Checklist')->find($id);


    if (!$checklist) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No se ha encontrado el checklist de id ' . $id);
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(ChecklistType::class, $checklist);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $checklist->setUserModificator($user);
        $checklist->setEstado(true);

        if ($editForm->get('Save')->isClicked()) {
            $em->persist($checklist);
            $em->flush();
        }

        if ($editForm->get('SaveCopy')->isClicked()) {
            $copy = clone $checklist;
            $copy->setNombre($checklist->getNombre() . ' #COPY' . substr(uniqid(), 8, 4) . '#');

            $em->persist($copy);
            $em->detach($checklist);
            $em->flush();
        }
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Se ha actualizado el Checklist correctamente.");

        return $this->redirectToRoute('listChecklist', array('id' => $id));
    }

    return $this->render(':checklist:create.html.twig', array(
        'edit' => true,
        'form' => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The form handles the entity Checklist, each Checklist will have a collection of ChecklistGroups, each group will have a collection of ChecklistGroupTasks and each task will have a collection of ChecklistGroupTaskCorrective. This 4 entities are handled in the form.

My approach works if there is no changes in the form when the "Save as copy" button is pressed. My approach also works if the only modification consist on the creation of new groups.

Problems start when I create both a group and new tasks nested in that group.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO checklist (Nombre, RotuloB, RotuloR, RotuloM, RotuloNA, RotuloValidador, Codigo, Estado, userCreator, userModifier) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["123", "1", "2", "3", "4", 1, "123", 1, 1, 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '123' for key 'UNIQ_5C696D2F3D3C9410'
```

My guess is Symfony is trying to create the copy and at the same time is trying to save the source Checklist, even when it's explicitly detached.

This is from my logs, somehow it's trying to execute two insert queries:

```
DEBUG - "START TRANSACTION" 
DEBUG - INSERT INTO checklist (Nombre, RotuloB, RotuloR, RotuloM, RotuloNA, RotuloValidador, Codigo, Estado, userCreator, userModifier) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
DEBUG - INSERT INTO checklist (Nombre, RotuloB, RotuloR, RotuloM, RotuloNA, RotuloValidador, Codigo, Estado, userCreator, userModifier) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
DEBUG - "ROLLBACK"
```

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok, now it's saving the new nested entities I create:

```
/** @var ChecklistGroup $newGroup */
            foreach ($copy->getGroups() as $newGroup) {
                $newGroup->setChecklist($copy);
                /** @var ChecklistTask $newTask */
                foreach($newGroup->getTasks() as $newTask)
                {
                    $newTask->setChecklistgroup($newGroup);
                    /** @var ChecklistTaskCorrective $newCorrective */
                    foreach($newTask->getCorrectives() as $newCorrective)
                    {
                        $newCorrective->setChecklistTask($newTask);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But, now I don't know how to handle the deletion, for example when removing a group. I tried detaching the group, but symfony is trying to delete it in the background and I get an error of... "Cannot delete detached entity".

Comment: can you add your entity anotation of Nombre and codigo?

Comment: Maybe it is a good and easier idea to instantiate new Checklist, set all its values from original one and then, persist and flush.

Answer (score 1):

your column `Codigo` in your entity has unique contraint.
It could be you are not changing the good attribute

```
$copy->setCodigo($checklist->getCodigo() . ' #COPY' . substr(uniqid(), 8, 4) . '#');
```

Comment: @Alvin I don't think that's the problem, neither the Nombre nor Codigo values have the setted values. Apparently it tries to insert the copy, and then it tries to update the original Checklist. In my logs I've a starting transaction, two inserts and then a rollback. I guess the problem is in the second insert.

Comment: it remember me my [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118421/update-an-entity-with-unique-key-insert-instead-of-update), can you try with `$em->merge($copy) ?`

Comment: No more errors after changing persist with merge, but the new copy only generated the main entity Checklist, groups, tasks and correctives didn't populate. Maybe the problem is the nested entities aren't getting linked to the copy? And then the cascade persist is trying to generate checklist from the inversed side? But how could I prevent that?

Comment: Edited question to add changes, I can handle new nested entities, now the problem comes with deleted ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your error message, @goto is right, there's a problem with this line:

```
$copy->setNombre($checklist->getNombre() . ' #COPY' . substr(uniqid(), 8, 4) . '#');
```

Because in the error message:

An exception occurred while executing
'INSERT INTO checklist
(Nombre, RotuloB, RotuloR, RotuloM, RotuloNA, RotuloValidador, Codigo, Estado, userCreator, userModifier)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
with params
["123", "1", "2", "3", "4", 1, "123", 1, 1, 1]:

The value "123" is the duplicate. So that is the problem. Why is it getting "123" which already exists in the database.