# Unique error persisting entity updates to db with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine in my Symfony project to manage the persisting layer in my application.

Recently, I've been having some issues when persisting changes from my entities to my database. The problem I've been having is that when I update an entity and save it to my database, sometimes the `EntityManager` treats my entity as a new object, so instead of performing an update operation, it performs an insert operation, thus causing a unique exception error in my database.

[As the docs say](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/doctrine.html#updating-an-object), when updating an object you should only perform these steps:

- fetch the object from Doctrine
- modify the object
- *(optional)* call `persist()` on the entity manager
- call `flush()` on the entity manager

> Note I added *(optional)* to the `persist()` call because, as the docs say, it isn't necessary since Doctrine is already watching the object for changes

Now that things are explained, this is the work I do in my code:

```php
$myEntity = $this->myEntityRepository->byId($id);

// make some changes to the entity
$myEntity->setSomething('something');

$this->myEntityRepository->save($entity);
```

Where the `save()` operation in my repository is as follows:

```php
$this->entityManager->persist($entity);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

And the `byId()` operation:

```php
return $this->entityManager->getRepository()->find($id);
```

As I said, the persist operation should only be called when persisting new entities, but since Doctrine can differentiate between an already managed entity and a new one, it should be no problem. If I didn't call the `persist()` method, instead of executing and insert operation and cause a unique violation, it would literally do nothing as it wouldn't detect any changes to my operations.
The reason I always use the `persist()` method is because the `save()` operation in my repository is used with both new entities and updates to existing entities.

As I've seen in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20118763/3272969), calling the `merge()` operation instead of `persist()` should solve the problem, but I don't see it right because I think it's just a "dirty" solution, plus the method [is being deprecated](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/1577) in future versions of Doctrine.

So, what am I missing here? Why sometimes I get a unique error when running the above code? I only have one connection and one entity manager configured in my application.

I'd like to add that the only occurrences of this problem are found in code executed in consumers (async events), not in the API itself, but whenever I receive a new event, a new and fresh connection to the database is created to ensure I don't have overlapping problems with the entity manager used in some previous event.

> When talking about consumers I mean that an event is published via RabbitMQ (the event contains the ID of the entity) and then it gets consumed in a separate process from the API, fetching the entity directly with the entity manager repository.

My guess is that between the line where I get my entity from the repository (i.e. I use the `find()` method) and the line where I save it into the database (i.e. I use the `flush()` method), the entity manager somehow removes the entity from its UnitOfWork so it treats it as a new entity instead of a managed one.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "async events" a bit more? Are you persisting to a queue in some fashion, or something similar?

Comment: @ChrisHaas The events get published to a RabbitMQ queue and later read from that queue and processed in a sepparate PHP process

Comment: The deprecation PR is from a while back and the [3.0 documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities) still lists `merge` as a viable method. However, per the PR, one recommendation is to store the unique ID of the entity and refetch it later if you need to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

An issue I recently found in some code was where an entity was being passed - via a RabbitMq message and the entity created from scratch,  including the id -- `$x = new Entity(); $x->setId($data['id');$x->setName($data['name'); # ... etc`).

Having an id set does not make the entity 'managed' by Doctrine however - only reading the original record (from the DB) and *then* updating it. Persisting $x as above will create a new record - and ignoring the id that was set.

I would ensure (perhaps with some assertions on the record that you are fetching that must pass - or die with an error, at least for now) so that know that you are always dealing with a known entity (I'm also presuming that your `->byId($id)` call is just a `->find($id)` internally).

Comment: When passing events through RabbitMQ messages I only pass the ID of the entity, so the entity is fetched from the repository when consuming the message, so the entity should always be known to the manager. Also yes, my `->byId($id)` call uses the repository `->find($id)` method.